# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this code giving me an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error?

It happens on line 4.

```
$featuredslider = $(".featured-slider")
if ($featuredslider.length > 0) {

    $featuredslider.royalSlider({ ********* error occurs here ********
        // options go here
        // as an example, enable keyboard arrows nav
        keyboardNavEnabled: true,

        tabs: {
            // thumbnails options go gere
            spacing: 0,
            arrowsAutoHide: true,
            fitInViewport: false,
            orientation: "vertical"
        }


    });

    slider = $featuredslider.data('royalSlider');

    slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) {
        if( $(window).width() < 481 ){

            //console.log($(slider.currSlide.content).data("slide"))
            $('.slide-overlay').removeClass("active");
            $('.slide-overlay[data-slide="'+ $(this).data("slide") +'"]').addClass("active")

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the variable and typing it directly? Are you mixing PHP into JavaScript here?

Comment: In the site I'm mixing PHP and JS but not here. When you say typing it directly, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Cut from past the equal sign in line 1, and paste it in line 4 instead of $featuredslider (but leave the rest). I can't imagine this is what the tutorial example looked like...

Comment: And I think you are mixing here, as there's an if statement.

Comment: Hi @Lee - I changed it to `$(".featured-slider").royalSlider({` and still get the same error.

Comment: Yeah you'll probably get errors but at least you'll be on the right path. Are you calling jquery prior to this?

Comment: Yes, I am calling jQuery.

Comment: Then we need to see more of your code, has this been taken from a tutorial? I'm sure the RoyalSlider docs don't appear like that

Comment: You're right. It's a custom bit of code but I can't think why it's giving me errors.

Comment: Because you're not calling $ correctly, sorry I can't help any further without your page code